# Container Format

Tags: file-format

What is the difference between File Formats and Container Formats?

Thank You,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A container format is a file format, but one that concerns itself with how data is stored in the file and not what the data is. Typical examples of this are video container formats such as avi or quicktime. These specify how blocks of video and audio data are stored in the file and how meta data describing the data and it's codecs are stored in the file, but they don't describe anything about the actual format of the video and audio data.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_(digital)

Comment: Does it mean , if i use the X container format, i can access any file format's supported by this X Container Format?

Comment: It means you can get the data out of the container along with meta data about it, but it won't help you interpret the actual data.